# How to apply a function to different dimensions of an array R?

Tags: r, arrays, function

The idea is simple but I have not been able to find any existing post that covers exactly that, I am sorry!
So I have an array of 4 dimensions: location(5) x species(5) x Season(6) x Depth (2). Like this matrix 12 times.

```
Season = 1, depth =  1
   [1] [2] [3] [4] [5]
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
[E]
```

My idea is to apply a diversity index for each dimension:

```
diversity(x, index = "shannon", MARGIN = 1, base = exp(1)).
```

The output should then be a list of 12 vectors, or a matrix of 12 vectors, or whatever, but a vector for each initial array dimension:

```
    [Shannon]
[A]
[B]
[C]
[D]
[E]
```

Thank you very much for your time and dedication whoever answer! :)

Comment: I think `apply` should work on an array like this.  Something like `apply(x, c(3,4), diversity, index = "shannon", base = exp(1))` - although you might need to play with the second argument to get the margin right.

Comment: It does, thank you very much!! What does the c(3,4) do, though? it is what i missed

Comment: It tells `apply` to loop through slices of the array consisting of the 3rd and 4th dimensions. For a 2-D matrix (the more common use of `apply`), 1 will loop through the rows and 2 will do columns. You should check carefully that it is doing what you think it is doing - it is easy to get lost in a 4D array!